# XSLT to map source to target

Tags: xslt

I have a source which has a element **personOrBusiness**

```
<xsd:element name="personOrBusiness" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:enumeration value="business"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="person"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

I want this to be mapped to FirmOrPerson any idea what xslt map should i write.

```
<element name="ContactParty">
       <complexType>
        <sequence>
         <element name="Language" type="string"/>
         <element name="Service" type="string"/>
         <element name="ContactRole" type="string"/>
         <element name="FirmOrPerson" type="string"/>
         <element name="Address" minOccurs="0">
          <complexType>
           <sequence>
            <element name="Street" type="string"/>
            <element name="HouseNumber" type="int"/>
            <element name="Box" type="string"/>
            <element name="City" type="string"/>
            <element name="ZIPCode" type="int"/>
            <element name="State" type="string"/>
            <element name="Region" type="string"/>
            <element name="Country" type="string"/>
             <element name="isInCityLimit" type="boolean"/>
            </sequence>
          </complexType>
         </element>
         <choice>
          <element name="Firm">
           <complexType>
            <sequence>
             <element name="legalForm" type="string"/>
             <element name="legalName" type="string"/>
             <element name="EnterpriseNumber" type="string"/>
             <element name="NACEcode" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
           </complexType>
          </element>
          <element name="Person">
           <complexType>
            <sequence>
             <element name="Title" type="string"/>
             <element name="LastName" type="string"/>
             <element name="firstName" type="string"/>
             <element name="NationalRegistrationNumber" type="string"/>
              <element name="PhoneType" type="string"/>
              <element name="Phone" type="string"/>
             </sequence>
           </complexType>
          </element>
         </choice>
        </sequence>
       </complexType>
      </element>
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: you are showing us XSD files. Please generate an example XML from your XSD. Then you can start from there :-) To automatically generate an XML from your XSD you could use an IDE such as "Oxygen XML Editor"

Comment: @Paul Okay i will go ahead download and install Jdeveloper a Free IDE and let me see i can get it to work

Comment: I don't JDeveloper. I know you can also develop XSLT using Eclipse. But I have only used it a few times, so I don't know if you can generate XML from XSD files.

Answer (score 0):

Google for xsl:choose and xsl:element

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_choose.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_element.asp

Comment: Please do not recommend that page (also see: http://w3fools.com/). There are numerous other tutorials, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858345/xsltwhich-is-the-best-tutorial-you-would-like-to-recommend

Comment: Thanks for the second link, quite a nice book selection there.